# How to clip movements to a bounding box?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, authentication, input, hex

I'm struggling to find the logic to output a series of pen positions based on some input format.

The pen's position data should be converted in a way that maintains a state of 'pen-down' and 'pen-up' (I have that working), and that clips any pen-movement beyond the rectangle area for the input (x = -8192, y = -8192) .. (8191, 8191). I could not make that clipping work.

See below instructions for how that clipping is supposed to happen:

**Instructions**
[image]

[image]

**Example of expected output**

inputData:
F0A0417F40004000417FC067086708804001C0670840004000187818784000804000

[image]

inputData:
F0A0417F41004000417FC067086708804001C067082C3C18782C3C804000

[image]

```
//For decode inputData//
let commands =[] , command , allPos = "", lastPos;

function proDecode(hex) {
    for (let i = 0, len; i < hex.length; i+=len) {

        // Opcodes take 1 byte (i.e. 2 hex characters), and 
        // numbers take 2 bytes (4 characters)
        len = hex[i] >= '8' ? 2:4;
        let num = hex.slice(i,i+len)
        if (len === 2) { // opcode
         command = []
         commands.push(command)
        }
        else{
           num = penDecode(num);
           console.log(num);

        }
        command.push(num)
    }
    console.log(commands);

    return commands;
}



//for outPut//
unction proOutput(commands){
    let isPenDown = false;
    let x = 0, y = 0;
    let output = "";
    let color = ""
    for (let [opcode, ...args] of commands) {        
        if (opcode === 'F0') {            
            x = y = 0;
            isPenDown = false;
            color = "CO" + 0 + 0 + 0 + 255 + ";\n";
            output += "CLR;\n";
        } else if (opcode === '80') {
            isPenDown = args[0] > 0;
            output += "PEN " + (isPenDown ? "DOWN" : "UP") + ";\n";
        } else if (opcode === 'A0') {
            color = "CO " + args.join(" ") + ";\n";
            output += color
        } else if (opcode === 'C0') {
            let allPos = "", lastPos;
            for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i+=2) {
                x += args[i];
                y += args[i+1];
                if(x <-8192){
                    x= -8192          
                } else if (x>8191){
                    x= 8191
                    lastPos = ` (${x}, ${y})`;              
                }else if (y<-8192){
                    y= -8192          
                }else if (y>8191){
                    y= 8191
                    output += "y PEN UP" + ";\n";
                } else{
                }
                lastPos = ` (${x}, ${y})`;
                if (isPenDown) allPos += lastPos;  
            }
            output += "MV" + (allPos || lastPos) + ";\n";
        } // else: ignore unknown commands
    }
```

**Expected Result**
Create the same output of the example above.

Comment: Did you look into line segment intersection, as I pointed out in my answer to your previous question on the subject? I don't see any traces of that. NB: the title of your question has nothing to do with the problem you want to address in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to find the intersection point with the bounding box whenever the coordinates move out of bounds (or come back within bounds). In some cases a line segment could even both enter and exit the box, giving two intersections.

To calculate an intersection point between a line segment (from *x<sub>1</sub>, y<sub>1</sub>* to *x<sub>2</sub>, y<sub>2</sub>*) and a horizontal line at *y*, you would use this formula for the *x*-coordinate:

*x = x<sub>1</sub> + (y - y<sub>1</sub>) * (x<sub>2</sub> - x<sub>1</sub>) / (y<sub>2</sub> - y<sub>1</sub>)*

Obviously the *y* coordinate of the intersection point is already given by *y*.

There would be no intersection when one of the following conditions is true:

- *y<sub>1</sub> < y and y<sub>2</sub> < y*
- *y<sub>1</sub> > y and y<sub>2</sub> > y*
- *y<sub>1</sub> = y<sub>2</sub>*

So to determine whether a line segment crosses one of the four sides of the bounding box (-8192, -8192) to (8191, 8191), you would check for 4 intersections. You could then find 0, 1 or 2 of such intersections.

Here is the code, which I adapted from my answer to your previous question (on hex encoding):

```js
function intersectionWithAxis(x1, y1, x2, y2, y) {
    if (y1 < y && y2 < y || y1 > y && y2 > y || y1 === y2) return []; // No intersection
    return [Math.round(x1 + (y - y1) * (x2 - x1) / (y2 - y1)), y];
}

function decode(hex) {
    let commands = [];
    for (let i = 0, len, command; i < hex.length; i += len) {
        // Opcodes take 1 byte (i.e. 2 hex characters), and 
        // numbers take 2 bytes (4 characters)
        len = hex[i] >= "8" ? 2 : 4;
        let num = parseInt(hex.slice(i, i+len), 16);
        if (len === 2) { // Opcode
            command = []; // start a new command
            commands.push(command);
        } else { // Number. Encoded in offset-binary, using 2 x 7 bits 
            num = ((num & 0x7F00) >> 1) + (num & 0x7F) - 0x2000; 
        }
        command.push(num); // Push opcode or argument in current command
    }
    return commands;
}

function disassemble(hex) {
    let isPenDown = false;
    let isPenInBox = true;
    let x = 0, y = 0;
    let output = "";
    let commands = decode(hex);
    for (let [opcode, ...args] of commands) {
        if (opcode === 0xF0) {
            x = y = 0;
            isPenDown = false;
            isPenInBox = true;
            output += "CLR;\n";
        } else if (opcode === 0x80) {
            isPenDown = args[0] > 0;
            if (isPenInBox) output += "PEN " + (isPenDown ? "DOWN" : "UP") + ";\n";
        } else if (opcode === 0xA0) {
            output += "CO " + args.join(" ") + ";\n";
        } else if (opcode === 0xC0) {
            if (!isPenDown) {
                for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
                    let [dx, dy] = args.slice(i, i + 2);
                    x += dx;
                    y += dy;
                }
                output += `MV (${x}, ${y});\n`;
            } else {
                let buffer = "";
                for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2) {
                    let [dx, dy] = args.slice(i, i + 2);
                    let toX = x + dx;
                    let toY = y + dy;
                    // Get intersections with top, bottom, left and right side of box:
                    let intersections = [
                        intersectionWithAxis(x, y, toX, toY, -8192),
                        intersectionWithAxis(x, y, toX, toY, 8191),
                        intersectionWithAxis(y, x, toY, toX, -8192).reverse(),
                        intersectionWithAxis(y, x, toY, toX, 8191).reverse()
                    ].filter(p => 
                        // Only keep the intersection points
                        p.length && p.every(x => x >= -8192 && x <= 8191)
                    );
                    if (intersections.length === 0) { // Position remains at same side of the box (inside or outside)
                        if (isPenInBox) buffer += ` (${x}, ${y})`;
                    } else if (intersections.length === 1) { // Moving from outside to inside of box, or vice versa
                        // Flush previous positions to output, move to the intersection point, and toggle the pen
                        output += `MV${buffer} (${intersections[0].join(", ")});\nPEN ${(isPenInBox ? "UP" : "DOWN")};\n`
                        isPenInBox = !isPenInBox;
                        // Start new series with positions
                        buffer = isPenInBox ? ` (${toX}, ${toY})` : "";
                    } else { // Moving from outside the box, through the box, and outside again
                        output += `MV (${intersections[0].join(", ")});\nPEN DOWN;\nMV (${intersections[1].join(", ")});\nPEN UP;\n`;
                    }
                    x = toX;
                    y = toY;
                }
                // Flush previous positions to output
                if (buffer) output += `MV${buffer};\n`;
            }
        } // else: ignore unknown commands
    }
    return output;
}

// Two samples as in question:
console.log(disassemble("F0A0417F40004000417FC067086708804001C0670840004000187818784000804000"));
console.log("---");
console.log(disassemble("F0A0417F41004000417FC067086708804001C067082C3C18782C3C804000"));
```

The code you posted in your question has some issues (which is why I used the original code without your changes to it):

- It is bad practice to use global variables like `commands`, `command`, `allPos` and `lastPos`: you change their values within your functions, which gives those functions [*side effects*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science));
- The `color` variable is set in the following statement, but this value is never used:

  ```
  color = "CO" + 0 + 0 + 0 + 255 + ";\n";
  ```

  Also, that value does not follow the required syntax (spaces are missing between the RGB values). Anyway, it serves no purpose in your function, so you can omit it.
- The following string does not include the *value* of `y`, but a literal "y":

  ```
  output += "y PEN UP" + ";\n";
  ```

  Also, generating the output at that spot in the code is wrong: you would need to flush the already gathered coordinates to the output first. And outputting `y` or its value at this point is not in line with the output syntax either.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can't find words to expressing my appreciation. Please allow me to ask to follow up question to understand the explanation about the formula for interaction point between a line segment. How come the y coordinate of the intersection point is already given by y? I try to understand the formula.

Comment: The y coordinate (last argument) represents a horizontal line (for instance the top side of the bounding box). Obviously all points on a horizontal line have the *same* y coordinate, so if there is an intersection point with another line segment, it will have that same y coordinate also, otherwise it is not on that line.

Comment: One more thing: this function is also used to get an intersection on a vertical line (for the left and right side of the box). In that case the x and y coordinates that are passed to the function are swapped, so every x is treated as an y, and vice versa. Then the return value of that function is swapped back with a call to `reverse`.

Comment: Does this answer your question?